# Best place to install pgBouncer for best performance (webserver or database)

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I have the following scenario:

- 2 to 5 `WebServers Apache` + `php` connecting on a single `postgresql` database. (the number of server's can variate to the traffic).
- Dedicated `PostgreSQL` (9.3) installed on the same network.

What is the best place to install `pgBouncer` in that scenario?

- Install `pgBouncer` on multiple webservers (each webserver with your own installation)
- Install `pgBouncer` on database machine.

Comment: One installation is easier to maintain than multiple installations. My choice would be an installation on the database machine.

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](https://pgbouncer.github.io/faq.html#how-to-use-ssl-connections-with-pgbouncer?) says:

**Should PgBouncer be installed on webserver or database server?**

*It depends. Installing on webserver is good when short-connections are used, then the connection setup latency is minimised - TCP requires couple of packet roundtrips before connection is usable. Installing on database server is good when there are many different hosts (eg. webservers) connecting to it, then their connections can be optimised together. 
It is also possible to install PgBouncer on both webserver and database servers. Only negative aspect of that is that each PgBouncer hop adds small amount of latency to each query. So it’s probably best to simply test whether the payoff is worth the cost.*

I prefer to have only one installation of pgbouncer, so it is either on the database server or on it's own machine (when I have more than one database server).
But as mentioned, you can do benchmarks for your setup to find out what suits you best.